# Need Help fixing

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
content += '<div class="btn btn-default payment_status_' + p_s + ' ld-ext-right payment_status_' + o_i + ' PaymentStatus">';
content += '<a href="#" class="update_payment_status ' + (p_s != 'unpaid' ? 'select_payment_slip' : '') + ' update_movement" id="update_payment_status_' + o_i + '" submit_type="' + o_i + '" >' + p_s + '</a>';
content += '<div class="ld p_loader ld-ring ld-spin" style="font-size:1.5em"></div>';
content += '</div>';
content += '<div class="btn btn-default order_' + o_s + ' ld-ext-right order_status_' + o_i + ' OrderStatus" >';
content += '<a href="#" class="update_status update_movement" id="update_status_' + o_i + '" submit_type="' + o_i + '" >' + o_s + '</a>';
content += '<div class="ld o_loader ld-ring ld-spin" style="font-size:1.5em"></div>';
content += '<span class="split_icon_real tooltip">' + (v['Remark'] != "" ? '<img src="Images/notification.png" class="tooltip_img" /><pre class="tooltiptext">' + v["Remark"] + '</pre>' : '') + '</span>';
content += '</div>';
```

Above is button section with loader

```
if (p_parent.parent('div').find('payment_status_' + orderID).click()) {
    if (process != '') {
        p_parent.parent('div').addClass('running');
    } else {
        p_parent.parent('div').removeClass('running');
    }
}
if (o_parent.parent('div').find('order_status_' + orderID).click()) {
    if (process != '') {
        o_parent.parent('div').addClass('running');
    } else {
        o_parent.parent('div').removeClass('running');
    }
}
```

Above is let the loader appear when it clicked

Any problem, I missed something with this? because when I press two button appear loader together.

Comment: Relevant code is missing in order to answer the question.  Where does the value of `process` change?

Comment: what is `p_parent` and `o_parent`? pplease try to create a working example of your issue so that we can check and understand

Comment: Nakumura, can you set up a sample demo of this functionality which you done..From @Gowtham K

Comment: p_parent is payment parent which was paymentStatus = $('.payment_status_'+orderID) something like this

Comment: @Nakamura.Kaito  untill you show us a working example of your problem or add relevant HTML+ full script code. We can't help you

Comment: sir can i message u boz it very long for coding